# Is it programmatically possible to track all the request from client to server in C#

Tags: c#, iis-7, httprequest, webrequest

I hosted a web application in IIS7.With in the server can i track the number of request and request details from client programmatically.

Please advice

Comment: In the IIS itself we can track the number of request.buit in functionality

Comment: Have you seen IIS Logging https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732079(v=ws.10).aspx? Do you need more than this? If so, what exactly?

Comment: I need so more...need get the excat URL from client,parameters if any ,time,how many unique urls. we can analysis certain things from these data.

Answer (score 2):

Within your app you can implement Application_BeginRequest() (in global.asax)

Inside this function you can use the Request object and you are probably interested in Request.Path, Request.RawUrl, Request.UserHostAddress, Request.InputStream, Request.Form.AllKeys.

Comment: This is helpful, but i can`t able to change any part in the hosted application.that why i am looking programmatically as a separate app.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you provide more details on what you'll be doing with the data, for example if the goal is to get analytics, then I would strongly suggest to instead use Google Analytics or other similar products (AppInsights, WebTrends, or others).

Having said that, you can certainly do that without modifying the application, you can write a managed code module that you register in the server through configuration that implements an IHttpModule, something like:

```
    public class TrackingModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;
        if (request == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string url = request.RawUrl;
        string userAddress = request.UserHostAddress;
        DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string userAgent = request.UserAgent;

        // Store somewhere the data...
    }
}
```

Long time ago, I gave a few talks on how to Extend IIS and wrote a SQL Logging Provider that could give you some context. This one uses the LogRequest event that is exactly suited for that. You just need to set it up in ApplicationHost.config or the root web.config and you will not need to modify anything in the application and you'll get all of that:

```
#define TRACE
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Hosting;

public class SqlLoggingModule : IHttpModule {
    public void Dispose() {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.LogRequest += new EventHandler(OnLogRequest);
    }

    void OnLogRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        try {
            Log(app.Context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());

            app.Context.Trace.Warn(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Log(HttpContext ctx) {
        string connectionString = @"server=(local);database=TechEd;uid=youruser;password=yourpassword;";

        // Disable Kernel Cache
        ctx.Response.DisableKernelCache();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText =
                "insert into Log (Date, Method, IPAddress, Url, UserName, UserAgent, ResponseCode, SiteName, ApplicationName) values" +
                              "(@Date, @Method, @IPAddress, @Url, @UserName, @UserAgent, @ResponseCode, @SiteName, @ApplicationName)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Method", ctx.Request.HttpMethod);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAddress", ctx.Request.UserHostAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Url", ctx.Request.Url.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", ctx.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserAgent", ctx.Request.UserAgent);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResponseCode", ctx.Response.StatusCode + "." + ctx.Response.SubStatusCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteName", HostingEnvironment.SiteName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationName", ctx.Request.ApplicationPath);

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```